# Missing Settings of online accounts in Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME 3.28.2

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-control-center

I have recently found that in my system, online accounts settings items are missing.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with GNOME 3.28.2.

I'm able to see full setups only using terminal command :

`env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center`

with root privileges (with sudo).

I tried to reinstall `gnome-control-center` or to put in the `.desktop` file the exec command `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center`. The result remains the same.

What is wrong?

**Update**

After running the command: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~`

I got the following:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/home/vladimir/.cache/doc/by-app': Function not implemented
chown: changing ownership of '/home/vladimir/.cache/doc': Function not implemented
chown: changing ownership of '/home/vladimir/.gvfs': Function not implemented
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall GNOME Online Accounts with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-online-accounts
```

and then retry starting GNOME Control Center.

Or try to launch GNOME Online Accounts directly by `gnome-control-center online-accounts`.

Other possibility is that you have messed permissions in the home folder. Restore them with

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache ~/.config ~/.local
```

---

Note: providing the `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME` before command is needed only if your current desktop environment differs from GNOME.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. Your recommendations sound quite reasonable, unfortunately they did not help to resolve the issue. Right now I can see the online accounts only if I use the command `sudo env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center`

Comment: Maybe the permission issue is wider, you can try to reown all files in the home folder by running `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~` and then reboot.

Comment: Trying to solve the problem, I have updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved the problem by a radical method. With help of USB stick I reinstalled Ubuntu into the same partition without formatting, in fact, overwriting my current configuration, now online accounts are shown again as before. The method has own disadvantage, I had to reinstall other software. An alternative idea is to create a new user account, however it also requires the re-installation of other software.